# Density independence

Tags: android, android-layout, resolution

There is a round circle in the center of my app. With a 480x800 resolution everything is perfekt, but in a 320x480 resolution the circle is too small. I have a circle.png in the drawable-hdpi folder with 470px x 470px. I tried to add a circle.png with 310x310 in the drawable-mdpi folder, but the result was the same.
This is the code of the layout xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"

    />
```

Is it possible that the circle has only a few pixels distance to the left and right edge of the display in every resolution?

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/857/apppv.jpg/

EDIT: I solved this problem in the end this way:

```
LayoutParams lp = indicator.getLayoutParams();
lp.width = (int) (disW-(disW*0.06));
lp.height = (int) (disW-(disW*0.06));
indicator.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

//This works perfectly well and the aspect ratio is correct.

EDIT2: This is not a solution at all, because the image quality of the scaled image is really bad...but i found two tutorials:
http://developer.sonymobile.com/wp/2011/06/27/how-to-scale-images-for-your-android%E2%84%A2-application/
http://android.creid.eu/how-to-resize-an-image-and-preserve-quality/

I have to work out which is the best way...

Comment: You should tag this with `[android-layout]` instead of `[layout]` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thoughts are to get your resolutions cleaned up.

Your images have numerically awkward dimensions. 470 = 2 * 5 * 47. Although, from a purely number-theoretical perspective, 47 is a fascinating number, it is doing you no good here because it cannot be decomposed to your benefit. Your other dimension, 310 = 2 * 5 * 31, is no better. The problem is that you're working with the (relatively speaking) big primes of 47 and 31. I don't know what your master image looks like, but, assuming that you only have the 470x and the 310x to work with, it is my suggestion to scale the 470x up, yes up, to 480x and from it derive all of your smaller images. My reasoning follows.

***My approach to image sizes***

Google recently (well, ok, a little while back) got their documentation act together and produced a top-notch [design guide for Android](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html). In particular, there is a nice little graphic on the page about [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

[image: Android densities]

I like to summarize this graphic as follows:

- xdpi : 8 (I know, I know, I skipped the 'h'. I think it's dumb here)
- hdpi : 6
- mdpi : 4
- ldpi : 3

But I disagree as to their using mdpi as "baseline". Instead, I engineer all of my master images to have width and height dimensions that are a multiple of at least 24 - the LCM (least common multiple) of the integers above. Sometimes it's handy to add a factor of 5, which would bring that LCM up to 120. If that looks too big, I might use 72 instead - a wonderful number with a bunch of 2s and 3s in it.

At any rate, when I choose a 'baseline' what I am choosing is a number that has as among its factors a handful of 2s and 3s, and on occasion a 5. Then I multiply that baseline by some power of 2, usually 4 or 8, to determine a size for my master image. This allows me to scale the master down in a number of different ways to suit design needs. BTW this is how Apple, et al, decides on things. (Did you ever notice that iPhone's 480 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 5? And for the 320 you swap out the 3 with another 2.)

Anyway, a master image size of 480 should work for you, because it seems to be in your ballpark in terms of absolute size (correct me if I'm wrong), and the slight up-scale at the beginning shouldn't cost you anything in the way of fidelity, because you're just going to scale it back down, or Android will.

And while all of that doesn't directly address your issue, I think it will help you out a little and bring things onto a more flexible foundation.

So that's my first thought :)

***Achieving percentages with LinearLayout***

My second thought is to bring some layout trickery to bear. This will be a little simpler, and will more directly address your 'equal borders' issue.

Use a LinearLayout organized according to this pesudo-XML:

```
<LL width=match height=wrap horizontal>
<View width=0 height=0 weight=.05 invisible/>
<ImageView width=wrap height=wrap src=mycircle/>
<View width=0 height=0 weight=.05 invisible/>
</LL>
```

The invisible views will act as spacers, the width of which will be determined by the layout engine at runtime and which will total .05 + .05 = .1 = 10% of the width of the screen, forcing your circle to occupy the remaining 90%. (You can of course adjust the .05 to whatever you like.) Android will then choose the proper of the ?dpi and force it to 90% of your screen size. The effort you put into choosing the various image dimensions above will pay dividends in fidelity when the image is scaled.

And that's my opinion as to the best approach to your problem. Switch the oddball 47 and 31 primes as factors of your image dimensions in favor of nearby numbers (48 and 32) which are composites of low primes 2, 3, and perhaps 5, and then coerce Android's layout engine using invisible spacer views.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If the circle image you have attached as link, is your choice of style. You could use this xml. And call this drawable to a relative layout or something as background also specifying its layout:height and layout:width in xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFF0000" android:endColor="#80FF00FF" android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 9 patch for this simple graphic.
Here is a very good explanation what is 9 patch and how to use it.
http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Comment: I thought about 9 patch too, but the graphic is very complex and has many details, so i think it is impossible to use 9 patch in this case.

Comment: hdpi/mdpi folders depends on pixel density, not on resolution. You can scale it programmaticly. You know screen resolution and orientation, just do the math and set dimensions programmaticly.